# Maximum concurrent HTTP requests to different hosts

Tags: c++, http, asynchronous, boost-asio

I'm building an app which needs to collect data(from now on I'll refer to this as update) from different hosts on local network. Some of the hosts would be updated more frequently than the others. I'm updating the hosts using async http requests. Every host will be updated only once a time. My question is how to determine the maximum allowed number of concurrent http requests to different hosts (one request/host).

I'm using the ASIO C++ library. The machine which runs this program has 4 physical cores and 12 gigs of RAM.

These are HTTP 1.0 requests, so when the reply arrived, the connection closes. The hosts are embedded devices, no HTTPS or SSL is required just pure HTTP POST/GET.

I thought there is a rule of thumb like when running paralell build with make, you pass the -j(number of cores the machine have) flag.

Comment: since when boost asio supply http mechanism? the last time I checked it's only about sockets, pipes and files.

Comment: Not easy to determine, but there is at least 2 upper limits : number of available descriptors to your process, number of available sockets slots in the TCP stack...

Comment: HTTP is just implemented on top of TCP which _is_ supported by ASIO. Here is an example code: [HTTP Async client](http://think-async.com/Asio/asio-1.10.6/src/examples/cpp03/http/client/async_client.cpp)

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs yes, for simple requests, maybe. what happes with redirections,proxies, SSL and HTTPS etc? polling a socket is maybe 10% of the work needs to be done.

Comment: The hosts are embedded devices. ATMEGA328P-s rinning a HTTP server. No SSL or HTTPS will be involved.

Comment: On linux you can get/set number of allowed opened descriptors with `ulimit -n` command and tcp protocol limits you with 64k ports. You can always try to `connect` and check its error code.

Comment: @frymode I wanted to know if it's there a rule of thumb like with make -j(number of cores)

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs the rule of thumb is - don't use HTTP, use a protocol like AMQP or MQTT. Seriously, the number of cores has nothing to do with the number of requests allowed. The type of request, how long it takes to process etc are important. Besides, most non-trivial HTTP servers use a request queue and throttling to avoid thrashing, exhausting sockets etc

Comment: @SzőkeSzabolcs moreover, it's unclear whether it's the devices that will act as servers. If they are, you can assume they'll be hacked 2 seconds after you turn your back. There's no way you can secure HTTP servers on IoT devices, even if you use SSL. The typical process is to have the devices poll a central server to post data *and* receive commands.